# Lucene MultiFieldQuery with WildcardQuery

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

Currently I have an issue with the Lucene search (version 2.9).

I have a search term and I need to use it on several fields. Therefore, I have to use `MultiFieldQueryParser`. On the other hand, I have to use the WhildcardQuery(), because our customer wants to search for a term in a phrase (e.g. "CMH" should match "KRC250/CMH/830/T/H").

I have tried to replace the slashes (`'/'`) with stars (`'*'`) and use a `BooleanQuery` with enclosed stars for the term. 
Unfortunately whichout any success.

Does anyone have any Idea?

Comment: OK, I think I've got it! MultiFieldQueryParser got a method "SetAllowLeadingWildcrad". This guy allow to put the wildcard char in front of the term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, maybe I have described it a little bit wrong.

I took something like this:

```
BooleanQuery bq = new BooleanQuery();

foreach (string field in fields)
{
    foreach (string tok in tokArr)
    {
        bq.Add(new WildcardQuery(new Term(field, " *" + tok + "* ")), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
    }
}

return bq;
```

but unfortunately it did not work.

I have modified it like this

```
string newterm = string.Empty;
string[] tok = term.Split(new[] { ' ', '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
tok.ForEach(x => newterm += x.EnsureStartsWith(" *").EnsureEndsWith("* "));

var version = Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29;
var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(version);
var parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(version, fields, analyzer);
parser.SetDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.AND);
parser.SetAllowLeadingWildcard(true);

return parser.Parse(newterm);
```

and my customer love it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the field shown is a single token, setting `setAllowLeadingWildcard` to be true would be necessary, like:

```
parser.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true);
Query query = parser.parse("*CMH*");
```

However:

You don't mention how the field is analyzed.  By default, the `StandardAnalyzer` is used, which will split it into tokens at slashes (or asterisks, when indexing data).  If you are using this sort of analysis, you could simply create a `TermQuery` searching for "cmh" (`StandardAnalyzer` includes a `LowercaseFilter`), or simply:

```
String[] fields = {"this", "that", "another"};
QueryParser parser = MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_29, fields, analyzer) //Assuming StandardAnalyzer
Query simpleQuery = parser.parse("CMH");
//Or even...
Query slightlyMoreComplexQuery = parser.parse("\"CMH/830/T\"");
```

I don't understand what you mean by a `BooleanQuery` with enclosed stars, if you can include code to elucidate that, it might help.